# I receive "Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was thrown." when trying to create new list item

Tags: microsoft-graph-api, sharepoint-online, microsoft-graph-sdks

I need to create a list item on my SharePoint List using Microsoft Graph SDK for .NET. My version is 5.23.0.

Here is my code I am using:

```
IDictionary<string, object> itemDictionary = new Dictionary<string, object>()
    {
        { "Tenant", "100" },
        { "LicenseLookupId", "1" },
        { "Quantity", 10 },
        { "Requester", "test@test.am" },
        { "RequestDate", "2023-08-22T00:00:00" },
        { "Status", "In Progress" }
    };

ListItem? listItem = new()
    {
        Fields = new FieldValueSet()
        {
            AdditionalData = itemDictionary
        }
    };

await this.graphClient.Sites[this.SiteId].Lists[listId].Items.PostAsync(listItem);
```

I reiceve a 400 error with this message

> "Exception of type 'Microsoft.Graph.Models.ODataErrors.ODataError' was
> thrown."

When I am using API request with the same values it creates the list item but I can't create the item using SDK.

Comment: Could you please specify the type of each field? I would suggest to check this [guide](https://github.com/microsoftgraph/msgraph-sdk-dotnet/blob/dev/docs/errors.md) how to catch ODataError. We need to know what's the error message.. Similar code works fine for me.

Comment: I just change App registration and everything worked even though the apps are identical.